# extract numbers in a string with parentheses when using get_line reading a file

Tags: c++

A question confuses me a c++ beginner for a time.

I have a lot of number data stored in a file in the following ways:

```
(123 34412 24)
(13 34324 2214)
(143 21342 24123)
(1323 341422 23244)
(14123 32342 2413)
....
```

and I want to read these data and hope to extract the first column to do some scientific calculations (the second and third columns are also expected to be extracted meanwhile).

I have no idea what data structure it is, and checked some references found no answer (seemingly not list, vector, etc).

I hope use a code kinda like as follows to do the work

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream file("input.dat");
    string lineBuf;
    int *col1[], *col2[], *col3[];

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(file, lineBuf)
            {
                //  how to convert lineBuf to separated numbers
                //  and assign to col1 col2 col3 separately here?
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone give me some hints how I should do for dealing with these data??

---

According to Nathan's answer

I tried the code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream file1("file1.dat");
    char eater;
    double a, b, c;
    string temp;

    while (getline(file1, temp)) {
        cout << temp << endl;
    }

    if (file1.is_open()) {
        cout << "is open" << endl;

        int lineNum = 1;

        while (file1 >> eater >> a >> b >> c >> eater) {
            if (lineNum >= 1 && lineNum <= 5) {
                cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
            }
            ++lineNum;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

to read the file1.dat containing

```
(1.01069 0.0216525 -0.00441842) // start line
(1.00634 0.00667446 -0.000859575)
(1.00557 0.00505487 -0.000599214)
(1.00487 0.00373986 -0.000414328)
(1.00213 6.22804e-05 4.43194e-06) // end line
```

while I cannot get correct a b c output

Comment: There's no function `std::get_line()` in the standard library.

Comment: Do you actually have a blank line between every data set? Also, do you have the same number of columns in every row?

Comment: sorry is getline

Comment: no there is no blank between lines, I have to add \n to break them here. each row has 3 numbers

Comment: @Eric In order to help fixing your code you'll need to show it. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: How would you skip the *leading* parenthesis if you were reading this from a regular `std::ifstream` and there was only one line? Do that, but do it from your `std::istringstream` instead. Without code, we don't have a clue what you're doing wrong, so update your question.

Comment: don't read lines when what you want is to extract a `char` from the stream which should be an opening paranthesis and then an `int` and ignore the rest till the next `'\n'`: `char ch; int value; if(!(inputstream >> ch >> value) || ch != '('){ inputstream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); return inputstream; } inputstream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); return inputstream;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have corrected the question, I just hope to know how to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: @WhozCraig question updated. I dont have a viable code, just for this kind of file, could you give some hint how to read the data?

Comment: @Eric I think Nathan gave you a suitable answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have tried that way while it can not jump the head part in the file

Comment: @Eric You probably didn't did it right.

Comment: if stuff like *// start line* is in the file, you are going to have to write a more complicated parser to eliminate it. Read the line into a string, find the open and close brackets, make a substring (`string_view` if you got 'em) between these brackets, put the substring into a `stringstream` and parse the  numbers out of the `stringstream`.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried to delete // start line but still not work. I will try your idea tomorrow I have to go to bed now... I am also thinking it is possible to define a struct to read all file into this type other information thus can be obtained together

Comment: Don't waste your time deleting. Read a line, get the contents of the line between the brackets. Parse the contents between the brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read line of numbers using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5005317/608639), [Reading lines with 2 numbers each in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19217991/608639) and [Reading multiple data types on one line using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21129480/608639)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `getline` here or any string manipulations.  We can leverage the fact the `operator >>` will only read in the type it is called with and it ignores white space to read in each of the individual numbers.

```
char eater; // this is to consume the ( and ) on each line
int number1, number2, number3;

std::ifstream fin("some_file_name.txt");

while (fin >> eater >> number1 >> number2 >> number3 >> eater) // will stop when it can't read anymore
{
    // do something with the numbers
} // loop back and read the next line
```

In the above code the first `>> eater` will read a single character.  This will "eat" the `(` at the beginning allowing us to use `operator >>` to get the 3 numbers.  the last `>> eater` consumes the `)` at the end and gets us ready to read the next line.

Comment: We could also generalize this solution using an array of numbers, instead of hardcoding deserializing number1, number2, and number3. Try to read integers and put them in a vector (or list), until no integer is in the stream, then read the eater

Comment: Might be worth having two eater variables and checking that they are equal to the expected `'('` and `')'`. A little more error checking wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @user9335240 I have updated the questions. unfortunately, there are some other strings in the same file and this code seems not suitable to deal with that together

Comment: @Eric Did you consider using a regular expression, to filter out those records which don't fit that pattern? Again. Post a [MCVE] of your file input and code please.

Comment: @Eric I've rolled back the edit to your Q as it invalidates this answer.  If you have more stuff in your file you should ask a new question on how to either read it in or ignore it if you don't care about it so you can get to point where you just have the lines with the numbers you need to read.

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry for changing the question, I append my code to the present question according to your kind prompt

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ code added... yes I know regex, if I can't find an easy way, I probably try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this snippet and reform it as you need:

```
std::list<float> readNumberListFromLine(const std::string &line) {
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    std::list<float> nums;
    char chr = 0;
    // Wait for a "(" token.
    while(1 == 1) {
        stream >> chr;
        // If failed to read a character, it means eof
        if (stream.fail()) break;
        if (chr == '(') break;
    }

    // Clear the stream state, to clear the "fail" bit, to allow reading more while we
    // check on this state
    stream.clear();
    while(1 == 1) {
        float num;
        stream >> num;
        // If failed to read a number, stream of numbers have stopped, don't read numbers more.
        if (stream.fail()) { break; }
        nums.push_front(num);
    }
    stream.clear();
    // This part shouldn't be like that, DRY principle says "Don't repeat yourself"
    // This should be in a function because it is a repeat of the first loop
    // But this would have templates and things that aren't simple
    while(1 == 1) {
        stream >> chr;
        if (stream.fail()) return std::list<float>();
        if (chr == ')') break;
    }
    return nums;
}

void printList(const std::list<float> &list) {
    // We don't want pop to affect the original
    std::list<float> copy = list;
    while (!copy.empty()) {
        // We pushed on the front,  so when we pop, pop from back, push/pop is a LIFO mechanism
        // Last-in-first-out,  we don't want this behaviour.
        std::cout << copy.back() << " ";
        copy.pop_back();
    }
}

void printListOfListsOfFloats(const std::list<std::list<float>> &data) {
    std::list<std::list<float>> copy = data;

    while(!copy.empty()) {
        printList(copy.back());
        copy.pop_back();
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream stream("/Users/fadi/code.dat");
    std::list<std::list<float>> data;
    std::string line;
    while (1 == 1) {
        std::getline(stream, line);
        if (stream.fail()) break;
        std::list<float> tmp = readNumberListFromLine(line);
        if (!tmp.empty()) { data.push_front(tmp); }
    }

    printListOfListsOfFloats(data);
}
```